# Securely Sending Sensitive Information to RESTful Service

Tags: c#, rest, security, azure, ssl

So I've searched and tried to piece together the various information I've found, and I apologize if this information *does* exist somewhere else. Not being a security professional I want to make sure that I do this correctly so as not to introduce some crazy security flaw.

I'm developing a RESTful service in C# that will be hosted on Azure that will allow users to login with username and password and then subsequent calls to the service will be associated with that user. The first client of this service is going to be a web app that communicates via javascript with the service (not sure if that makes it any different).

So here's what I've sort of come up with as a workflow:

- User lands on the site
- User enters username and password
- Information is sent to service

  - This is where I have the least amount of detail
- Service authenticates user credentials
- Service returns a token to be used by subsequent service calls

I've read about SSL and I know Azure supports SSL certificates, but I'm not 100% sure it's everything I'm looking for. Just by having an SSL cert and using HTTPS, does that make it okay to send plain-text user information to my service? That doesn't sound right. If not, what else do I need to do to be able to securely send this (and potentially other) sensitive information to my service?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is talking to a service hosted on Azure from JavaScript, you want to take a look at [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js). Vittorio Bertocci describes exactly how to secure such an application in [this article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/).

When using SSL/TLS, the transportation channel is encrypted, so anyone intercepting the packets cannot read the clear text. You obviously still need to protect your application from other attacks that could lead to information disclosure (things like SQL injection etc). Look at the [OWASP top 10 cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet) for more info.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to implement my security based on one client (Javascript). Also using AD addresses a singular problem of user authentication which, although it is currently my focus, is not the entire problem.

Comment: The ADAL library is also available for other type of clients. See here for an overview: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/Dn151135.aspx

Comment: Oh, that's great. But isn't AD only for identities? I wouldn't want to fill my Azure AD with customers. I assumed the Azure AD was for system admins, service accounts, etc.

Comment: No, you can register users, group and applications in AAD. You can also sync users from an on-premise Active Directory to AAD. Or you can have AAD federate back to an on-prem ADFS for authentication.

Comment: Would this be the ideal, secure way to manage customer account credentials?

Comment: If you are managing their accounts, you can create them in your AAD directory. If you want them to manage their accounts in their own AAD, look at multi-tenancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at how Azure implements its own REST API for service bus etc. It uses shared access keys. Instead of sending user id and password to the REST API, the client forms an authentication string and creates an hash of the authentication string using the shared key and sends the string to the server. The REST API authentication logic would then form the same information and if it arrives at the same hash, then the client is authenticated and token that can be used for subsequent calls is sent to the client.
Shared keys adds another layer of security than just sending passwords over https.

Take a look at the service bus sample code [Service Bus Brokered Messaging REST Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh416754.aspx) on MSDN. Specifically "Step 3: Create Management Credentials" describes this process.